# Trigger.io Reload - can't reload to my live app

Tags: trigger.io

I am struggling to apply reload to my live app. does it need to be the same config version with the live one?

a bit of background:
after the first time my app is release I never use the reload, and I changed few files (around 5-6 files js, html and css) and I also change to new config 2.0 and push to stream in default one. but it seems didn't work, I tried both device Samsung Galaxy Note2 and Iphone5. I open up the app and close it using back button and wait 15 mins (it has been 2 days)

I also tried to change the config back to original 1.40, and tried 1.4.51 and push the stream but it seems does not work.

However I can make it working on my simulation, everytime I put a new stream. my simulation will straight away download it.

is there something I missing or am I misunderstood of how reload work? any help please?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3):

For reload to work, you need to use the exact same config (not only the same API version) as the app you want to be updated.

You should see an overview of all existing configs in your Trigger Toolkit Reload tab. This is also the place where you can switch back to the specific configs.

Comment: Hey Patrick.. Thank you for replying, How do I know which version is my live one from the reload log? there are heaps of version I can see and different stat on Active User. the lowest one is v1.4.26 but no v1.4.
I have just switch the config back to v1.4 from my svn. but when I push the stream its still saying v1.4.51, and did update my app in live

Comment: From the reload tab you cannot see which versions were actually uploaded to the store. For the future you should consider maintaining a history of released versions including your svn commit number and forge version at the time of releasing. This makes things much easier down the road.

Comment: There are a couple of other hints which could help you identify the right version - if you know the date when you built / packaged and submitted the app, you could look for configs created on or just before that date. You can also see active user numbers against each config.

Comment: @PatrickRudolph sorry correction for the word I wrote, "and did update my app in live" its actually it didn't update my app.

Comment: @AmirNathoo I will try to check which version before, and will try to update it from each version. 

just wondering my app was release about 5-6 months ago but in the log I see version:
v1.4.41(4 months ago) has 9 active users. also if I see the version v1.4.51 (2 months ago) has 7 active users. 

could you please explain it? does it mean 9 people using v41 and 7 using v51?
Thank you

Comment: Hi Guys, I managed to make it working, its actually v1.4.41 (5 months ago) with 5 users. Thanks for your guys help. appreciate it.